# Combinatorial And

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

How do you enter a Combinatorial And in Raster Calculator in ArcMap 10.8.2?

The old information say is a "CAND" which I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combinatorial-and.htm):

> `CombinatorialAnd(in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2)`